# Do Scala futures support for non-blocking combinators such as firstNCompletedOf and firstNSuccCompletedOf?

Tags: scala, future

For instance, Folly supports the non-blocking combinator collectN which can be found here https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/futures/helpers.h

It does not provide a non-blocking combinator collectNWithoutException which would only collect successful futures similiar to collectAny but for more than one resulting future.

Scala seems to provide only firstCompletedOf which would be collectN with n == 1.

How can I easily implement these non-blocking combinators if Scala does not support them?
I would like to use the existing combinators for the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is not practical for big number of futures, but a demonstration of available combinators

```
  def firstNCompleted[T](n: Int, futures: List[Future[T]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[List[T]] =
    Future.firstCompletedOf(futures.combinations(n).map(Future.sequence(_)))
```

- creates all combinations of n futures `Iterator[List[Future[T]]]`
- sequences each combination into Future of resulting list `Iterator[Future[List[T]]]`
- returns first completed `Future[List[T]]`

Comment: Maybe you should move the *"This is not practical for big number of futures"* before the code snippet, otherwise it's a bit too shocking. One should also note that once one of the futures is completed, the others are not canceled in any way.

Comment: Nice but what about firstNSuccCompleted?

Comment: Scala does not have combinators for only successful futures, you will need to write your own function like in @Dima answer. Otherwise I would suggest to take a look at reactivex patterns using Monix or RxScala http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is `collectN`:

```
def collectN[T](n: Int, futures: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] =  {
  val promise = Promise[List[T]]
  var result:List[T] = Nil
  futures.foreach {
     _.onComplete { 
       case _ if result.length >= n => 
       case Success(t) => synchronized {            
         result = t :: result
         if(result.length == n) promise.success(result.reversed.take(n))          
       }
       case Failure(x) => promise.failure(x) 
     }
  }
  promise.future
}
```

Note, that it returns a `Future` that will never complete if the number of input futures is less than n (and they all succeed). 
You can modify it trivially to keep waiting until N successes rather than aborting after first failure, but that would also end up waiting forever if less than N of futures end up succeeding. To avoid that, you could count the number of the ones that have completed, and bail out after it reaches the size of the original list.

Comment: Well, this is the way I had implemented it myself but checking that futures.size >= n before. It is similiar to Folly's implementation, so the answer would be: Scala does not support them but you can implement them similiar to Folly with the help of promises.